# What is the maximum size of a MySQL database in version 5 and up?

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum size of a MySQL database in version 5 and up?

I do not mean the maximum size of row or table, but the maximum size of the whole database.

Answer (score 4):

Two billion (2'000'000'000) tables and a max total of 64TB for InnoDB. MyISAM tables are files, so it's underlying OS file limit.

Check this answer: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,158,165

Answer (score 3):

It's dependent of your operating system. I.e. on Windows its dependent on maximum folder size.

[This documentation entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html) is very helpful in regards to this

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size for MySQL databases is determined by operating system constraints on file sizes for tables, not by MySQL internal limits.

Answer (score 2):

its all depend on the OS

```
Operating System                     File-size Limit
Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32                   2GB/4GB
Win32 w/ NTFS                        2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit               2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+  (using ext3 file system) 4TB
Solaris 9/10                         16TB
MacOS X w/ HFS+                      2TB
```