# What database to use for large files

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of just 4 columns. But everyday, about 180 new rows are added to the table. Is MySQL fast and efficient enough to handle this much data?

I have a cron job on this data that runs hourly.

Thanks!

Comment: How large are those columns? A few gigabytes each? :)

Comment: You mention 'large files' in the title. How large are the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But everyday, about 180 new rows are added to the table.

That is a laughably small amount of data for a database. Databases are designed to hold millions or even billions of records, and to operate at very high frequencies (like, many inserts per *second*). 
Don't worry about it.

Related: [What is the maximum size of a MySQL database in version 5 and up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625930/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-mysql-database-in-version-5-and-up)

Answer (score 1):

Just a 180 rows a day should be absolutely no problem.

Answer (score 0):

On average a shared hosting server with just one instance of MySQL server running serves ~ 200 + Wordpress blogs, day after day.

Just a heads up.