# MySql community edition capacity

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am using MySql community edition on Amazon RDS service. It is very large database, 2/3  tables has about 10 millions records and 4-5 tables has 7-8 millions records. Now My question is, How much capacity MySql community edition has? Should I have to purchase MySql Enterprise edition for my application? Where Can I get pricing information for the same?

**EDIT:**

What is the benefit/key fetcher to use MySql Enterprise Edition?

Thanks -

Answer (score 7):

There is no capacity limit for MySQL Community Edition (only OS limit).

You don't need MySQL Entreprise Edition.

Read this post : [What is the maximum size of a MySQL database in version 5 and up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625930/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-mysql-database-in-version-5-and-up)

If you don't join your large tables, it should be okay. Otherwise I recommend you to use another RDBMS (like postgres...).